# Reusability of redux/react based containers

Tags: reactjs, redux, scalability, reusability

I didn't find any article properly explaining ways of doing that. So the problem is the following. Imagine you have react container connected to redux store, and communicating with a BE. Now you need to reuse it on multiple pages and (the worst case scenario) in lists. So what would you do with actions, selectors and reducers to achieve this. Solutions I'm using right now are awful spikes and they tight every single container to application architecture so badly, I can't think of anything worse. The best case scenario is creating new redux instance for every container. That kinda works, but leads us to other problems, and makes me think about react context vs redux. If you had such issue please share your thoughts. How did you solve that?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I understood 100% your problem, so correct me if I'm wrong. You have a container linked to redux state and you would like to re-use it multiple times without fetching the data each time?

You could wrap that container into another one. The wrapper would take care of fetching the data (e.g. on mount). This will update your redux state then your containers will have new data. All in one BE call.

edit:

```
function getData(id) {
    // Call to backend
    dispatch({ type: 'GET_DATA', payload: { id: id, item: response } })
}

export default function reducer(state, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'GET_DATA':
            return {
                ...state,
                items: { ...state.items, [action.payload.id]: action.payload.item },
            }
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: More or less correct, but say they have some id they use for fetching data. Each instance uses different id. And say I want to create a package of it.

Comment: So basically I want to reuse the same reducers, selectors, and actions to modify different state branches.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by package.

If you don't have an API to fetch all your data in one call (like returning a list of items) then you're forced to get them one at the time.

Normally I try to expose an API where I can get a list of all my items (or brief object of what I need for display) and have another one for a more detailled item.

Comment: By package I mean javascript package like npm.

Comment: ok, one container instance fetches data for id=1 another one for id=2 on the same page and they could use the same reducers, actions and selectors, but I can't achieve that with standard redux tools.

Comment: I didn't try to package stuff yet but the concept should be similar. Let's say you have your redux state: { items: {} }. When you receive your response from your backend, you can add it using the id. So it'll look like: { items: { my_id: { ... } } } and so on. You can reuse the same service/action/reduce

Comment: Right, what about actions? You can't use the same action type for all of them. And it's just one of the problems.

Comment: Use params on your function. Let's say: `getData(id)` and then your reducer uses that id to add the item to your object of items in your state. I can edit the answer to make it clearer

Comment: Yeah, that's what I'm doing. And it doesn't look to me like good architecture. I'd even say it's awful.

Comment: Oh then I don't know any other way. Let me know if you find something better :)

Comment: That's exactly why I've opened this thread :) But I definitely upvote your post because for now it's the only way I can think about.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding your response to @Fleezey correctly I think you may be looking for something like this (dumbed down version).

**Component**

```
class Container extends Component {
  ...
  someHandler = ({safeId, params}) => dispatch.someAction({safeId, params})

  render() {
    return <p onClick={this.someHandler({safeId, params})}>Model Stuff</p>
  }
}

export default connect(store => {
  const safeId = this.props.model.id.toString()

  [safeId]: store.content[safeId]
})(Container)
```

**Reducer**

```
const content = (state ={}, action) => {
  const safeId = action.safeId.UpperCase()

  switch (action.type) {
   case `SOME_${safeId}_CONTENT`:
     return myContentFunc(state, action)
   default:
    return state
  }
}
```

You should be able to achieve what you're trying to do by refactoring your standard setup by adding an ID variable that get's passed around.

Comment: It's pretty much the same thing. It's just that in my modules I have more data (like isLoaded, isLoading, lastReceived, etc...) and I have a `data` field where I keep track of my backend data. In the end, I'm adding data to an array/object based on the ID

Comment: Yup, this is solution, but it's far from being perfect, I expect to have setup when I say something like: "import Container from 'mypackage'; <Container useReduxBranch="mypagename.mycontextname.myid">" and bam! It works. And I definitely don't want to use root level reducers.

Comment: But it would definitely lead us to the whole new level of complexity. So I might agree that the way you described is the only possible from what I can think about so far.

Comment: @Fleezey, that's pretty much how I'm doing it as well. Store can get pretty complex, but I'm using types, collections and model stores to keep it organized. If it's well structured it can be a very simple solution to a rather complex situation. The real work happens in my api actions.